# Saving multiple child entities in EF results in key values conflict

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a recipe entity that has a collection of image entities. In my controller, I attempt to save a new recipe with two new images attached to it:

```
_recipeService.Insert(recipe);

 try
 {
 foreach (Image img in recipe.Images)
 {
      _imageService.Update(img);

 }
 _recipeService.Save();
```

In the background, I'm using the Unit of Work pattern to ensure that all the services are using the same DbContext, and calling Save() on any service will save all entities. So, if I attach two images to my recipe during creation, I get the following error when I attempt to save:

```
AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.
```

I'm sure it has to do with the fact that both image entities have an ID of 0. What's the best practice here?

FWIW, here is my initial migration:

```
public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Recipe",
            c => new
                {
                    ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    CategoryId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Title = c.String(),
                    Summary = c.String(),
                    Directions = c.String(),
                    CookingTime = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    CreationDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    PostedDate = c.DateTime(),
                    LastModifiedDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    Visible = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    TagList = c.String(),
                    Ingredient_ID = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Category", t => t.CategoryId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Ingredient", t => t.Ingredient_ID)
            .Index(t => t.CategoryId)
            .Index(t => t.Ingredient_ID);

CreateTable(
            "dbo.Image",
            c => new
                {
                    ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    RecipeId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    ImageUrl = c.String(nullable: false),
                    MainImage = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Recipe", t => t.RecipeId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.RecipeId);
```

Thanks,

Chris

**EDIT: Adding code for the recipe service**

using Barbecurian.Data;
using Barbecurian.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

```
public class RecipeService : Service<Recipe>
{
    private IService<Tag> _tagService;

    public RecipeService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IService<Tag> tagService)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _tagService = tagService;
        _repo = _unitOfWork.RecipeRepository;
    }

    public override void Insert(Recipe recipeToCreate)
    {
        List<Tag> tags = new List<Tag>();
        foreach (Tag tag in recipeToCreate.Tags)
        {
            if (_tagService.Get(filter: t => t.Name == tag.Name).Count() > 0)
            {
                tags.Add(_tagService.Get(filter: t => t.Name == tag.Name).SingleOrDefault());
            }
            else
            {
                Tag newTag = new Tag() { 
                    Name = tag.Name
                };

                _tagService.Insert(newTag);
                tags.Add(newTag);
            }
        }

        recipeToCreate.Tags = tags;
        // Validation logic
        if(Validate(recipeToCreate))
            _repo.Insert(recipeToCreate);            
    }

    protected override bool Validate(Recipe recipeToValidate)
    {
        //Ensure recipe has a unique title
        if (_repo.Get(r => r.Title == recipeToValidate.Title).Count() > 0)
            _validationState.AddError("Title", "That title already exists.");

        return _validationState.IsValid;
    }

}
```

}

This inherits from:

```
public abstract class Service<TEntity> : IService<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IModel 
{
    protected IRepository<TEntity> _repo;
    protected IValidationDictionary _validationState;
    protected IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, 
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, 
        string includeProperties = ""){
        return _repo.Get(filter, orderBy, includeProperties);
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetByID(int id, string includeProperties = ""){
        return _repo.GetByID(id, includeProperties);
    }

    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity){
        _repo.Insert(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(object id){
        _repo.Delete(id);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entity){
        _repo.Delete(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        _repo.Update(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Save()
    {
        _unitOfWork.Save();
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        _unitOfWork.Dispose();
    }

    protected abstract bool Validate(TEntity entity);

    public IValidationDictionary ValidationState
    {
        get
        {
            return _validationState;
        }
        set
        {
            _validationState = value;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: show the implementation of _recipeService

Comment: Have you tried using a lock to ensure you're not calling Save in a threaded way that could result in a race condition? Also, do you really need to call Update on all the images? Shouldn't EF walk the tree and find all the entities it needs to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe calling insert on adding new images

Comment: I'm hoping I can keep the entire operation transactional. If one insert fails, I don't want to commit any part of the operational.

Comment: The unit of work guarantees that so you can do whatever you want and only you call save the operations will be commited

Comment: Groan... I didn't notice I was calling Update() when I should have been calling Insert(). Thanks for the spot.